# Visual Studio Option hangs

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Have anyone experience a problem when you click OK button in Visual Studio 2010, VS would hangs? VS used 100% of cpu power of one of cores. Event I didn't change any setting and click OK, it would still run into this issue.

Comment: Try devenv.exe /resetsettings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imported the default "Visual C# Development Settings" (.vssettings) and it fixed the issue.